# group_by example from tidyverse in not working

Tags: r, dplyr

I am not able to work this example from tidyverse
https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html

```
>mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(mean = mean(disp))
mean
1 230.7219
```

What might be wrong ?

Comment: It looks like you probably have loaded `plyr` after `dplyr` (part of `tidyverse`) and ignored the warning - the older `plyr` package has a version of `summarize` that doesn't respect grouping. You can fix an instance by specifying `dplyr::summarise` instead of just `summarise`, but in general if you need the `plyr` package load it *before* you load `dplyr`.

Comment: oh thats right. Thank you.